# Thread appears to never exit

Tags: c, pthreads

In my `main()` I create a thread, named `startup()` that is supposed to initialize everything and launch a new thread called `callback()` that should handle the I/O and stuff. My problem is callback() never exits and it appears to be in a loop and as I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it quits and eventually executes code placed in other threads. I can't figure out what is not working properly, so I am hoping for some help.

```
void *startup()
{
/*... SOME OTHER CODE FOR CONNECTION OVER NETWORK... */
if ((thread_op_status = pthread_create(&callback_tid, (void *) 0, 
                                        callback, (void *) 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (cc.debug)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore #%d - pthread_create()\n", errno);
        }
        set_global_error(&error_flag, CLIENT_INTERNAL_ERR);
        pthread_exit((void *) 0);
    }
if ((thread_op_status = pthread_join(callback_tid, (void *) 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (cc.debug)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore #%d - pthread_join()\n", errno);
        }

        set_global_error(&error_flag, CLIENT_INTERNAL_ERR);
        pthread_exit((void *) 0);
    }

    pthread_exit((void *) 0);
}

void *callback()
{
    int access_granted = 0;
    int action;

    fprintf(stdout, "Seleziona: ");
    scanf("%d", &action);
    if (action == LOG)
    {
        access_granted = action1();
    }
    else if (action == ABT)
    {
        access_granted = action2();
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid choice.\n");
    }

    pthread_exit((void *) 0);
}
```

Comment: Does `callback` still not exit if you remove all the code from it? If it does exit, narrow it down to the problematic code.

Comment: 'void *startup(void *arg)' - thread functions take a parameter, though with termination via a pthread_exit() call, rather than a return from the thread function, I would not expect a problem, (?).

Comment: @interjay still doesn't exit, apparently.

Comment: Does any other thread (besides `callback`) read `stdin`?

Comment: @user58697 no other thread reads from standard input.

Comment: I've cut and pasted your code skeleton into a sample program replacing undefined function calls like `action1()`, `action2()`, and `set_global_error()`, and written a `main()` which spawns `startup()` and it works as I would expect it to.  The code you've posted here seems fine.  How are you determining that it is `callback()` that isn't exiting?  What is the output of your program when you run it?

Comment: Your thread function `callback` is not fine, it doesn't have the correct prototype. Just define it as receiving `void*` even if you don't use the parameter. Calling functions with a different list of arguments (that is what `pthread_create` does) has undefined behavior. Also casting `0` to `void*` is completely superfluous.